# CouchDB loop unique `_id` and Console.log that via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

I Have 3 Records
`"_id": "20"`,`"_id": "30"` and `"_id": "40"`.

How Can I Console.log `_id`?

I want to Get This Output

```
    20
    30
    40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found very easy solve of problem :

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.user && doc.title) { // This check is important
    emit(doc.user, {id: doc._id});
  }
}
```

Then query it :

```
GET /yourdb/_design/app/_view/by_user?key=film42
```